# Function calculation

Tags: functions

This looks easy but it's been so long I'm totally lost...
Question :
Calculate
$f(2000)$

with the following information:

$f(11) = 11$

[$f(x+3) = \frac{f(x)-1}{f(x)+1}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%2B3%29%20%3D%20%28f%28x%29-1%29%2F%28f%28x%29%2B1%29)

Thank you for your help, and a a step by step would be helpful

cheers

Answer (score 6):

Denote $g(x)=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$.
Note that $g(g(x))=-\frac{1}{x}$ and hence $g(g(g(g(x))))=x$ is the identity function. Now can you compute $f(x+12)$ in terms of $f(x)$ and then compute the desired term?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $2000=11+1989=11+3\times 663$ so you can get to $2000$ in $633$ steps.

I would suggest putting $f(11)=t$ and just working out where those steps take you, one by one, to understand the way the function works.

Comment: Or note that $ 2000=1991+9=181*11+9 $, so it will require, if I am not mistaken, 181 steps.

Comment: @hetajr how do you add $11$ using the functional equation you are given - that tells you how to add three.

Comment: Note that $9=3+3+3$. You get to $1991$ and then use $1991=181*11$, it's my idea. I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your time... however I'm not sure hwere to start (and also english isn't my native language so i'm having trouble following your leads )

Comment: @FrançoisAuclair Use the functional equation to compute $f(14)$ and then $f(17)$ - I suggest using $t$ for $f(11)$ since the formulae look as though they might get complicated, and this simply reduces the number of symbols on the page. It is useful to use a letter rather than the number $11$ initially because this helps to understand what cancels and why.